# CSS Columns layout does not work on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, multiple-columns

I was trying to create a layout with 5 columns,
the height should be stretch by its content,
so i cannot set a fixed height for it,
but it doesn't work in my codepen work
https://codepen.io/yyywork/pen/MWGLJwN

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#outer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

#inner-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  column-count: 5;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  break-inside: avoid;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-container">
  <div id="inner-container">
    <div class="item item-1">
      <b>Col 1</b> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type sp
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
      <b>Col 2</b> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </div>
    <div class="item item-3">
      <b>Col 3</b> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </div>
    <div class="item item-4">
      <b>Col 4</b> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </div>
    <div class="item item-5">
      <b>Col 5</b> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type sp
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not how columns work. Item 2 & 3 fit together into _one_ column, with the height resulting from the "higher" items - so they get _put_ into one column. It sounds like you don't actually want CSS Columns here in the first place - but perhaps much rather make your inner container a flex container as well, and set `flex: 0 0 20%` for the items ...?

Comment: Exactly. NB that `height: 100%` of every wrapper and item there does effectively nothing, that's why items 2 & 3 are short and stack below each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below CSS its working perfectly on Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

```css
#inner-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: stretch;
}

.item {
      flex-basis: calc(100% / 5);
      border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-container">
  <div id="inner-container">
    <div class="item item-1">
      <b>Col 1</b> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type sp
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
      <b>Col 2</b> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </div>
    <div class="item item-3">
      <b>Col 3</b> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </div>
    <div class="item item-4">
      <b>Col 4</b> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </div>
    <div class="item item-5">
      <b>Col 5</b> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type sp
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO, Thanks for your contribution in this community, it is always good to have some explanation of what you are answering and why your answer resolves the issue. if possible you can add the [source link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to make your answer look apart from others.